# Abrir Activity de acuerdo al Item seleccionado en ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

¿Como hacer que un item del listview de Android me abra una “activity distinta” de acuerdo al Item seleccionado?

He declarado estas variables en el archivo java, pero me marca en rojo `adapterView`

```
package com.example.juan.pruebaprueba;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listviewmodelo;
String[] listviewlista = new String[] {
        "Elemento 100",
        "Elemento 200",
        "Elemento 300",
        "Elemento 400",
        "Elemento 500",
        "Elemento 600"
};
List<String> convertString;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    listviewmodelo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    convertString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listviewlista));

    arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, convertString);


    listviewmodelo.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

// Esta parte me ayudaron en StackoverFlow


listviewFontChange.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    // Abre una nueva Activity:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nuevaactivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }
    );


}


}
```

Comment: Cambia `listviewFontChange` por `listviewmodelo`

Comment: Gracias:  cnbandicoot Lo que intento es hacer que de acuerdo al item que seleccione de un listview de android studio se me "abra una activity distinta", por ejemplo si selecciono el ítem 1 se me abra una activity que hable de los cereales; si escojo el ítem 2 se ne abra una "activity distinta" a la anterior que hable de otro tema y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente estas obteniendo la referencia de un ListView dentro del layout `activity_main.xml` y es `listviewmodelo`  :

```
listviewmodelo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

por lo tanto debes usar esa instancia para configurar el listener, y no la de `listviewFontChange` :

```
  //listviewFontChange.setOnItemClickListener(
  listviewmodelo.setOnItemClickListener(
```

---

De acuerdo al item seleccionado se puede definir mediante el valor de `position`:

```
listviewmodelo.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (position == 0){
                    // Abre una nueva Activity:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), nuevaActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    }else if(position == 1){
                    // Abre una nueva Activity:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), segundaactivity.class);
                   }else if(position == 2){
                    // Abre una nueva Activity:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), terceraActivity.class); 
                   } 


                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Gracias chicos los adoro!